# Can we supplicate to Allah without wudu/ablution?

Tags: dua, taharah

Can we supplicate to Allah without wudu/ablution, at any place, at any time?

Comment: Your question is already covered here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33292/how-is-a-women-in-her-menses-supposed-to-make-dua-without-making-wudu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is a women in her menses supposed to make dua without making wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33292/how-is-a-women-in-her-menses-supposed-to-make-dua-without-making-wudu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can, at any place, any time. Salah requires Wudu/Ghusl but making Dua or reciting God's names or reciting the Quran does not. However as, with wudu, you are in a purer state, it is good etiquette to make Dua in the best manner ie. with Wudu.

In the place of excretion, it's probably unpreferred.

Comment: please don't answer questions which are duplicate. please consider: [How to Answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and take a tour [Help](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help)

Answer (score -1):

You need wudu to touch the Qur’an Al-Kareem. You can recite by heart without wudu, but to touch the Qur’an Al-kareem you do need wudu