# How can someone turn to Allah in times of crisis?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, dua

Imagine someone is going through a personal crisis, and they desperately and immediately need to turn to Allah.  However, they can't: they need to make wudu, identify qiblah, cover their awrah, and perhaps even wait until menses has finished.  Being in a state of crisis, they're incapable of doing these things, so they don't turn to Allah.

This feels inherently wrong.

**Question**: How can someone turn to Allah in times of crisis?

The answer to this question [How is a women in her menses supposed to make dua without making wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33292/17163) indicates dua is possible during menses.  [This question has an unreferenced answer [Can we supplicate to Allah without wudu/ablution?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33504/17163); it might be correct, but I can't tell without references.]

[*Note*: I initially wrote the real motivation for this question (which is personal), but deleted it before posting, as I was worried that people would misinterpret it as an advice question and offer opinions about a highly personal topic.  So I'll just ask the bare-bones question.]

Comment: Basically Allah is close to you and you can call him at any time, anywhere and in any state based on (2:186) http://legacy.quran.com/2/186 wudu'(ablution), qiblah etc. are recommended but not necessary I think I even answered a question or at least mentioned that a woman doesn't need to be covered to do suplication. And based on the Quran there's no evidence for the need of being in a pure state nor identifying the qiblah.

Comment: The conditions you listed in your question are only necessary for the obligatory prayers five times a day. Asking Allah swt for help and mercy at any other time does not have these conditions.

Comment: This is indeed inherently wrong. One can call upon Allah at all times and in all forms (see [Qur'an 3:191](https://quran.com/3/191)). In fact, not doing so (calling upon Allah) is wrong (see [Qur'an 40:60](https://quran.com/40/60)) — one has to always call upon Allah and turn to Allah, especially in times of crisis.

Comment: There is detail fiq on the subject of menstruation.https://www.amazon.com/Birgivis-Manual-Interpretted-Complete-Menstruation/dp/1590080467/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1493361609&sr=1-1&keywords=birgivi%27s+manual

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualikum

Allah says in the quran that he is with those who bear patience(sabr):

> " O you who have believed, seek help through patience(sabr) and prayer.
>   Indeed, Allah is with the patient."[2:153]

Also our prophet(pbuh) says:

> On the authority of Abu Yahya Suhaib bin Sinan (May Allah be pleased with him) it is related that the Prophet (Peace be upon him) said,
>   “How amazing is the affair of the believer. There is good for him in everything and that is for no one but the believer. If good times come his way, he expresses gratitude to Allah and that is good for him, and if hardship comes his way, he endures it patiently and that is better for him.”

You must repent to Allah for all the sins that you have done because Allahs says in the Quran:

> "Whatever of misfortune strikes you, it is what your right hands have earned. And He forgives much."[42:30]

Also know that nothing can befall you except what Allah has decreed for you. Therefore you must have tawakkul(Trust in Allah):

> Say: "Nothing shall ever happen to us except what Allah has ordained for us. He is our Maula (Lord, Helper and Protector)." And in Allah let the believers put their trust.[9:51]

I hope you are able to go through this crisis with patience, and you repent sincerely to Allah and all your sins are wiped away.

Answer (score 0):

The bare minimum is to turn your heart towards Allah...if one is a shitpile still if their heart is towards Allah then they're good, but if they have the best of clothes, made wudu, are towards Qibla, have hijab but their heart is somewhere else— (e.g.) praying/speaking to Allah only for *riya* then it's no good. For more about turning your heart towards something see [from bad to good](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/38292/13637) section of my answer from here.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question should be reverse, 'How can someone turn to Allah in happy times?', because it is easy to turn to Allah in time of crisis: crying, falling down in sajuad (prostration), invoking His mercy, reminding Him about good deeds we did only for His sake, reminding how you got in the middle of night to pray or how you let go a bad thought by without acting on it. There is so many way, and they all will rush to you, when you view Allah as someone with love of 70 mothers (hadeeth). How would you embrace your mother in crisis.. ? That is how we embrance Allah (sw) at time of crisis, and it is just happens for believers.

But it is difficult to turn to Allah (sw) in happy times. it is really difficult and in fact it is difficult to get up from super bowl and offer magrib.